# Android Navigation Component keeps reloading WebView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-architecture-navigation

Today I faced a problem with `WebView` inside a `Fragment` using `Android Navigation Component`.
In my case, in `Fragment1` there is button under `WebView`. User needs to scroll down to click it. After clicking it, a new destination is opened (`Fragment2`). Then, when user goes back to `Fragment1`, `WebView` is reloaded, and viewport is scrolled to the top again.

It's extremely annoying. User might been scrolling down for minutes, and it always throws him to the very top after coming back. Can I somehow prevent it from reloading / scrolling back to top?

Example code could be as simple as that:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    webView.loadData(getString(R.string.some_very_long_html), "text/html", "UTF-8")
    buttonBelowWebView.setOnClickListener {
      navigateToFragment2()
    }
  }

}
```

If `WebView` contains videos, loading might take even up to 5 seconds. It's terrible experience.

I tried adding flag to load only one time, but then `WebView` is empty when navigating back from `Fragment2`:

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

  var loaded = false
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if(!loaded) {
      webView.loadData(getString(R.string.some_very_long_html), "text/html", "UTF-8")
      loaded = true
    }
  }

}
```

Note that in real life I use `ViewModel`s and observe data from rest api, but the problem stays the same.

Also, example code I provided is written in Kotlin, but if there is solution in Java, then it's appreciated too.

Is it possible to not reload `WebView` and reset scroll position when navigating back from nested destination?

Comment: are you using the `AndroidX` webview, or the platform one?

Comment: I'm using `android.webkit.WebView`. Is there `AndroidX` one?

Comment: yeah, I only learned about it last week myself! https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebViewCompat

Comment: @Blundell It's not a view though but a helper class, isn't it?

Comment: I think it because of your fragment getting resumed trying to move your webview load to onCreate if you have done in onResume or onStart

Comment: @ArulMani I'm doing it in `onViewCreated` as in example, which could translate briefly to `onCreate` I suppose.

Comment: Maybe create a small example to show your problem. It will be then easier to figure out what could be done to solve it.

Comment: @xinaiz did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 11):

This is how fragments work in their basic form (which is what the Navigation Components use)

The fragments themselves are saved, but their views are destroyed.

This is what happens in your scenario:

- Fragment 1 created
- Fragment 1 view created (This contains the webview)
- Button clicked
- Fragment 1 view destroyed
- Fragment 2 created
- Fragment 2 view created
- Back clicked
- Fragment 1 view re-created
- Fragment 2 view destroyed
- Fragment 2 destroyed

If you weren't using Navigation Components, this would be very easy to solve using non-hacky ways.
You could simply use `.hide()` combined with `.add()` on a FragmentTransaction instead of `.replace()`, and the fragments views would not be destroyed.

But seeing as you're using Navigation Components, you aren't handling the fragment transactions yourself.

A workaround would be the one posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039009/2877453

As the fragment and their variables are saved, you could save your view as a variable in the fragment.
Then check in onCreateView, if the variable is null, inflate it like normally, if not null, then return your saved view.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I did in the end! I was not sure if it's good solution though. I will post it as answer when I have some free time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code before change fragment:-

```
if (getVisibleFragment() instanceof Fragment1){
      // do nothing
}else{
      // replace fragment
}


    public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
                if(fragments != null){
                    for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
                        if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                            return fragment;
                    }
                }
                return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please changes to this

```
class Fragment1 : Fragment() {

 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    webView?.loadData(getString(R.string.some_very_long_html), "text/html", "UTF8")
   }

}
```

give a try

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

this will be implemented in the fragment that has webview

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        // inflate your layout here
        return view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.community_home_layout, container, false);
     }else {
      return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey there when ever you come in fragment first time or coming back its method onViewCreated always call again and again, if you want something like you don't want to reset you can do it by one global boolean check because that global variable will not be change after fragment resumes

**Like this**

```
var shouldLoad = true
```

And then what ever you want to do

```
if(shouldLoad){
  //do your work

  //setting false to your boolean
  shouldLoad = false
}else{
  //if you need something else
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do this webView is empty when I go back. `onCreateView` is called when I come back, so new layout is inflated, thus "new" webView is empty.

Comment: This does not work as onCreateView is called and view inflated, if more details is required please add.