# Android Fragment navigation back previous page

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

I am try to user one activity in my project。
in main fragment i user viewpage and tablayout，the ViewPager contain five fragment, in first fragment contain two fragment i form one fragment navigation to new fragment, when back i lose all data in the ViewPager's fragment.

just like this
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-5BrEAydbuoIwK-v_esDRRm9Pb6U33cX/view?usp=sharing)

as @Ail tell me. i fix this bug.

Code before:

```
protected View mView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(getRootView(), container, false);
    initView();
    initData();
    return mView;
}
```

Code after:

```
public View mView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mView == null) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(getRootView(), container, false);
        initView();
        initData();
    }
    return mView;
}
```

Comment: can you give code snippet for your fragment transactions ?

Comment: @Shasapo I konw how to fix this bug

Answer (score 1):

You are having one Activity which means you are using architecture Navigation component.

When you navigate back to main screen, your callback methods like `onViewCreated` recalled. You should keep a reference to the View you created the first time in main screen and return it again, as suggested by **Ian Lake** :

https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1103522856535638016

Also look at [Fragments destroyed / recreated with Jetpack's Android Navigation components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581071/fragments-destroyed-recreated-with-jetpacks-android-navigation-components)