# Action back / onbackpressed at fragment make field at previous fragment recreate and that make field clear value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have two fragment in my app. The first is login, the second is OTP fragment. In OTP fragment when I press onBackPressed() the value in textfield at login fragment is missing. How I can make all value in textfield at login fragment still exist?

Comment: Have you read the documentation on [saving your fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state)? Any `EditText` will retain its state automatically if it has an `android:id`.

Comment: ya, I use TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout and I set the `android:id`

Comment: Is it retain state just for `EditText`?

Comment: You can bundle up the value and send it back to the login fragment, when `onBackPressed()` is called

Answer (score 0):

Which methods do you use to open OTP framgent ?? Add or replace.

Maybe you are using replace so when you press back, the view of login fragment will be recreated

You may find the diff here:
[Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

Comment: I'm using android navigation, but before go to OTP fragment I open Dialog(context: Context)

Comment: As i know Navigation use replace method. So it will recreate the view @CadisHangoluan

Comment: You can  read this post for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581071/fragments-destroyed-recreated-with-jetpacks-android-navigation-components